# Search for a location inside of a area radius

Tags: java

I am building a minecraft plugin.

Basically my world limit is set by radius off the spawn location, instead of having 4 corners to determine the limited region of the world.

So my world limit is a round radius for example of distance of 1000 blocks.
Now I want to place a small 50x50 round area of blocks inside of that area of 1000 blocks radius, so I need to find a random coordinate which will be the center point of the round area I am going to make.

**Question**

1. How to get a random coordinate in a radius based area, is there an equation for that? I can't just do spawnX + rand(-1000,1000) and for spawnZ, because the area is round.
2. How can I make sure that the whole round area I want to put in will fit in the big radius area?

Comment: why you don't use circle formula for your coordinates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To pick a random spot in a circle would be a random angle and a random number within the radius:

```
random_angle = random(2π)
random_dist = random(radius)
random_x = cos(random_angle) * random_dist
random_y = sin(random_angle) * random_dist
```

To ensure a round area fits into another round area you calculate the distance from the middle for the small round + its radius and as long as that's equal to or less than the bigger round then it fits in.

To find the distance is a² + b² = c². So subsitute that for x and y to get:

```
distance = √(x_diff² + y_diff²)
```

This all assumes your co-ords start at (0, 0) in the middle of the map circle. If not you can calculate that by adding half the width and height to all co-ords.

Comment: If my area i want to generate has radius 50, and the radius of the world is 1000, means that if I get a random point at radius 950, I can suit that area in any generated coordinate right?

Comment: This is the correct approach. Using polar coordinates is neat and simple.

Comment: @BenBeri yea just minus the smaller radius from the bigger one and it will fit!

Comment: Note that this isn't exactly random.  Points closer to the center will be favored more than points closer to the edge.

Comment: C.f. here for how to make a uniform distribution on a disc: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/120527/simulate-a-uniform-distribution-on-a-disc

Comment: Here's another good explanation: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiskPointPicking.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want each point of your circle to have an equal chance of being selected, you can generate a set of polar coordinates instead, then convert it to cartesian coordinates.

Generate these random numbers:

- `r`: between 0 and 1000
- `theta`: between 0 and 2π

Assuming the centre of the circle is (0,0), the cartesian coordinates are:

```
x = r * cos(theta)
y = r * sin(theta)
```

To ensure that the smaller circle with radius 50 is inside the big circle, just limit `r` to be between 0 and 950 instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your problem correctly, but I think you can use circle formula for your coordinates. In a circle, we always have:

`X^2+Y^2=R^2`

so if you select `x = spawnX + rand(-1000,1000)`, then you can calculate possible `y` range with aforementioned formula.